# Run helm3 client from in-cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Helm 3 does not provide any way to create an action.Configuration structure if the code is running from within the cluster.

I have tried by building my own generic flags:

```
config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
insecure := false

genericConfigFlag := &genericclioptions.ConfigFlags{
    Timeout: stringptr("0"),
    Insecure: &insecure,
    APIServer: stringptr(config.Host),
    CAFile: stringptr(config.CAFile),
    BearerToken: stringptr(config.BearerToken),
    ImpersonateGroup: &[]string{},
    Namespace: stringptr(namespace),
}

actionConfig := &action.Configuration{
    RESTClientGetter: genericConfigFlag,
    KubeClient: kube.New(genericConfigFlag),
    Log: log.Infof,
}
```

Unfortunately, this result in a SIGSEGV error later when running `action.NewList(actionConfig).Run()`.

Is it the right way to define an action config for Helm 3 from within a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: What is an "action"? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: action is the Helm package that allows to performs "actions" against the client: https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.0.2/pkg/action?tab=doc. All those actions require a Configuration (https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.0.2/pkg/action?tab=doc#Configuration). However there do not seem to be an API for in-cluster code.

Comment: oh right, thanks. Then the "in cluster" difference is just how you setup the connection to the kube api?

Comment: I think so - using the cli package removes my SIGSEGV error though but I still can't connect, receiving a `context deadline exceeded`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, and works fine for me (using helm 3.2.0 level sdk code):
**imports**

```golang
import (
    "log"

    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action"

    "k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
)
```

**ActionConfig**

```golang
func getActionConfig(namespace string) (*action.Configuration, error) {
    actionConfig := new(action.Configuration)
    var kubeConfig *genericclioptions.ConfigFlags
    // Create the rest config instance with ServiceAccount values loaded in them
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Create the ConfigFlags struct instance with initialized values from ServiceAccount
    kubeConfig = genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false)
    kubeConfig.APIServer = &config.Host
    kubeConfig.BearerToken = &config.BearerToken
    kubeConfig.CAFile = &config.CAFile
    kubeConfig.Namespace = &namespace
    if err := actionConfig.Init(kubeConfig, namespace, os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), log.Printf); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return actionConfig, nil
}
```

**Usage**

```golang
actionConfig, kubeConfigFileFullPath, err := getActionConfig(namespace)
listAction := action.NewList(actionConfig)
releases, err := listAction.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
for _, release := range releases {
    log.Println("Release: " + release.Name + " Status: " + release.Info.Status.String())
}
```

It is not much different from what what you originally did, except the initialization of the actionConfig. It could also be that newer version fixed some issues. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To run helm 3 in-cluster you need to modify the source code.
[Here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/6cc039ea79a435c9f335d677b78d9be574b8e770/pkg/action/action.go#L138-L145) is the function:

```
func (c *Configuration) KubernetesClientSet() (kubernetes.Interface, error) {
    conf, err := c.RESTClientGetter.ToRESTConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "unable to generate config for kubernetes client")
    }

    return kubernetes.NewForConfig(conf)
}
```

This line `conf, err := c.RESTClientGetter.ToRESTConfig()`

change to `conf, err := rest.InClusterConfig()` 
and compile the code.

You can also try modifying code in a way that resulting binary is universal and can run out of cluster as well as in-cluster.

Let me know if it's helpful and if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I would like to avoid modifying the helm source code directly and rather use the interfaces of the library. It is really weird that they do not provide a way to run the code directly from the cluster.